# How to avoid unnecessary copies with `boost::variant` recursive XML structure

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, boost, variant

Let me refer to [the following example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/mini_xml___asts_.html#spirit.qi.tutorials.mini_xml___asts_.the_structures) from the boost spirit tutorial about parsing
a "mini XML" data structure. My question doesn't actually have anything to do with
spirit, it's really about `boost::variant`, and making efficient "recursive" variant
structures.

Here's the code:

```
struct mini_xml;

typedef
    boost::variant<
        boost::recursive_wrapper<mini_xml>
      , std::string
    >
mini_xml_node;

struct mini_xml
{
    std::string name;                           // tag name
    std::vector<mini_xml_node> children;        // children
};
```

In the tutorial, they go on to show how to "adapt" the `struct mini_xml` for `boost::fusion`,
and then write spirit grammars that load data into it.

However, it occurred to me recently that there's a subtle issue in this example that may lead to significant overhead.

The issue is that the `variant` type, `mini_xml_node`, is not no-throw move constructible in this example. The reason is that it contains `boost::recursive_wrapper`. The `recursive_wrapper<T>`
always represents a heap-allocated instance of `T`, and it does not have an empty state. When a
`variant` containing `recursive_wrapper` is moved from, a new dynamic allocation is made and a new `T`
is move constructed from the old `T` -- we can't simply take ownership of the old `T`, because that would leave the old variant in an empty state. (I only looked into this after I was trying to implement my own variant type -- this is indeed what `boost::variant` does afaict, and it is indeed not no-throw move constructible in this example.)

Because `mini_xml_node` is not no-throw move constructible, the container `std::vector<mini_xml_node> children` will be on the "slow path" -- when it uses `std::move_if_noexcept`, it will elect to copy the elements rather
than move them. This happens for instance every time the vector capacity increases. And when we copy a `mini_xml_node`, we copy all of its children.

So for instance, if I want to parse from disk an xml tree which has depth `d` and branching factor `b`, I estimate that we will end up copying each leaf of the tree about `d * log b` times, since pushing back into a vector `b` times causes reallocation about `log b` times, and it will happen for each ancestor of the leaf.

I don't have an actual application right now where I care about this overhead, but it's easy for me to imagine that
I might. For instance I might want to write a high-performance parser using spirit for some small utility program
that will check that e.g. a data file has a certain form, or count some statistic of it or something. And then it
might very well be that the time to parse dominates the overall runtime of the utility, so these copies might be performance critical.

The question is, what is the simplest and cleanest way to change the code to prevent these copies from happening? I thought of a few approaches
but maybe you see a better way.

1. Quick and dirty: Write a wrapper class that contains a `mini_xml_node` but the move constructor is explicitly marked
   `noexcept`, even though it isn't really `noexcept`. This will cause termination if an exception is thrown, but that should be pretty rare...
2. Use an alternative to `std::vector` that doesn't use `std::move_if_noexcept`, and instead just uses `move`. If I understand right, `boost::vector` does this. The tradeoff is it doesn't have strong exception safety, but it's not clear if that's really a problem here.
3. (This one doesn't actually work.) Add `boost::blank` as one of the options for `mini_xml_node`.

When `blank` is one of the value types, `boost::variant` has special code that adapts its behavior -- it will use
`blank` as a natural empty state when default constructing and when making type-changing assignments.

However, it appears that putting `blank` into `boost::variant` doesn't go so far as allowing me to no-throw move construct
the variant even though it contains a `boost::recursive_wrapper` type. Tested on coliru with boost `1.63`:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87620e443470b70c

(Maybe this would be a useful feature for `boost::variant` in the future? What I'd like is that the move constructor transfers ownership of the recursively-wrapped guy, and puts the old variant in the blank state, and marks the move constructor as `noexcept`.)

Comment: Qi doesn't afford move-semantics, in general. If you can use X3, it has a `x3::variant` utility that might have move-semantics. You could look at whether it does a better job. Now, in general I don't think recursive variants can be nothrow-moved because allocations are usually involved.